How do I animate an arm equipping a weapon without animating the whole skeleton?
I want to make a character be able to equip a weapon while standing and moving. How do I just animate the arm while the rest of the skeleton is in a running animation? How do I set this up correctly?
Also is there a name for this? I'd like to look up tutorials.

Search for Layered Animation, the NLA editor, baking animation.

Ah thanks for the name :)
